# How to resolve 'The expected [App\Events\UserRegistered] event was not dispatched.' error?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, registration

I have created a feature called `test` to test the admin registration. When i run the testcases it gives me this error

```
 1) Tests\Feature\Admin\RegisterTest::testValidRegistration
  The expected [App\Events\UserRegistered] event was not dispatched. 
 Failed asserting that false is true.

 /var/www/html/gas-backend/tests/Feature/Admin/RegisterTest.php:85
```

Below i have stated the admin registration test file and user registered event file

**Admin/RegisterTest.php**

```
$response->assertStatus(201);
        $response->assertJson($expectedResponse);
        $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', $expectedDatabaseRecord);
        Event::assertDispatched(UserRegistered::class);
        Notification::assertNotSentTo($user, RegistrationComplete::class);
```

**UserRegistered.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Models\User;

class UserRegistered
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        //return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

How should i resolve this error ?